# Only one field appears after converting .shp to raster to .asc, in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am a beginner in the GIS world. I tried to convert the .shp map to the raster .asc map. I did Raster-> Conversion-> Rasterize then as shown below there are only 1 of 4 fields appears. So I cannot convert the map based on the field that I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use a **numeric** field.

What is the type of the other fields?

Comment: The others are string. How do I change it to numeric?

Comment: You can add a new field in the field calculator and apply as an expression your text field like "name_of_your_string_field". Create one field for each text field. Be careful, your fields should only include numeric and not alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that first.

Comment: You're Welcome!

Comment: I converted the map to .asc using land-use type field (e.g building=1 etc). So expected that the map value will be the numbers of the land-use type. However, when I open the file with notepad, all values are zero. I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: Add a screenshot of all your tool parameters, you can create a new post for this question.